# Combining $hasOne and $hasAndBelongsToMany in a Model- is this possible/legal?

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0. I searched in the manual for quite awhile and I've searched google/stackoverflow as well.

I'm still somewhat new to cakephp. I've been working on trying to get $hasAndBelongsToMany (many to many) working, and I did get that working...wahoo. But, with the same model, I'm unable to get the following scenario below working.

I have Activity and User models. An activity can have many users. A user can have many activities. But, I want to display the list of activities, along with the owner of the activity, all in one row in a table, on my web page.

Activities table includes the following columns, among others:

- id
- name
- status
- owner_fk (foreign key to Users.id)

Users table includes the following columns, among others:

- id
- username
- password
- role

My SQL would look like:

```
select usr.username, actv.name 
from users usr, activities actv
where usr.users_id = actv.owner_fk
```

**Activity Model** (User model has similar code):

```
class Activity extends AppModel {   
    var $name = 'Activity';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' =>
        array(
            'className'              => 'User',
            'joinTable'              => 'activities_users',
            'foreignKey'             => 'activities_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'users_id',
            'unique'                 => false,
            'conditions'             => '',
            'fields'                 => '',
            'order'                  => '',
            'limit'                  => '',
            'offset'                 => '',
            'finderQuery'            => '',
            'deleteQuery'            => '',
            'insertQuery'            => ''
        )
    );
```

I'm not sure if CakePHP allows mixing/matching in the same model, for example...having a $hasOne and also having a $hasAndBelongsToMany, in the same model. There is probably a simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do, and/or a best practice. I've experimented some, but no luck so far.

I would like to do something in the code below in my controller, but with the condition such as on my where clause in my SQL above.

```
$this->set('results', $this->Activity->find('all'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier from the User model Direction.  Really you are asking Cake to get you all the user detail & activity detail for which that user is a owner.

so you would have something more like:

```
$this->set('primary_user_with_activity', $this->Activity->User->find('all'));
```

According to Cake conventions, that owner_fk field should be user_id - and the Activity model should be set up with a belongs_to relation to user to define the owner.

Then set up the User model to have a has_one relation to match the belongs_to in the activity model

If you then want to add a has_and_belongs_to_many relation, you can do that - give it a different alias than the belongs_to relation.

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'People' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
        )
    );
```

More details in here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

It does take some getting used to, but following the conventions really helps.

Comment: Will, thanks for the answer. Last night, I found the answer on my own, but similar to what you suggested here. I added a belongsTo to my Activity model, which points to my User model. That did the trick. I'll have to revisit my id naming conventions too.

Comment: cool, glad to hear you worked it out.  Once you get the conventions right cake is such a pleasure to develop with

Comment: ps - please accept the answer if it is correct - or write up what you did to help people who find this in the future.